# Accessing the Mount Teide summit when all 200 permits per day are already booked

Tags: spain, mountain-climbing, canary-islands, permits, tenerife

I'm going on a trip to the Canary Islands and would not like to miss accessing the Mount Teide summit, but:

> Access to the summit itself is restricted; a free permit is required
> to climb the last 200 m (660 ft). Numbers are normally restricted to
> 200 per day.
>
> *Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teide*

Reservations can be done on the [Teide National Park web site](https://www.reservasparquesnacionales.es/real/ParquesNac/usu/html/inicio-reserva-oapn.aspx?cen=2&act=%201). Problem is, it shows **no vacancies left** at that time. Without any hope, I have emailed the park to let me know of last-minute cancellations.

Are you aware of any other way to access the summit without permit?

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why would you go against regulations ?

Comment: As a new user asked from the locals, please respect the limits, as this is a fragile eco-system and it is very heavily taxed as it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just found out that I will be able to access the peak!

By booking a night at the [Altavista refuge](http://www.telefericoteide.com/en/altavista/altavista-refuge), they let us climb to the peak in the early morning (only)

> #### Access to the crater
>
> It is advisable to leave the refuge at about 6 am, to reach the Teide crater before dawn.
>
> When you stay overnight at Altavista del Teide Refuge, you are
> entitled to access Teide Peak without having to apply for the permit,
> which is otherwise required.
>
> Source: http://www.telefericoteide.com/en/altavista/plan-your-visit

---

> #### El Teide from Montana Blanca with an overnight stay at the Refugio Altavista
>
> For the true mountain enthusiast, the only 'real' way to
> climb El Teide is from Montana Blanca, but to include an overnight
> stay at the 60-bed Altavista Hut before rising early the next morning
> to reach the Pico del Teide in time for sunrise. This is the one
> scenario where you don't need a permit, but you DO:
>
> 1. need to be at
>    the summit early as you must be off the Telesforo Bravo trail before
>    9am,
> 2. need to provide evidence when you exit at the Telesforo
>    Bravo gate that you stayed at the Refugio Altavista the night before.
>
> Be aware that it's not cheap to stay in the Altavista refuge - €20 per
> night for adults at the time of writing.
>
> Source: http://www.winstercavers.org.uk/Walk_Tenerife_El_Teide.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can also book a tour with an accredited tour guide.

For example here : https://www.volcanoteide.com/en/activities/hiking

Comment: But could they arrange for permits at relatively short notice when the official limit of 200/day is already used up?

Comment: Yes, they have access to more permit ;)